# Print() getting ignored

Tags: python, syntax-error, runtime-error

When I run this:

```
from firebase import firebase
from sanction import Client

client_pin = ''
client_id = 'valid_id'
client_secret = 'valid_secret'
request_token = 'state'
access_token = ''

query_url_wss = 'wss://developer-api.nest.com'
query_url_https = 'https://developer-api.nest.com'
auth_url = 'https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=%s&state=%s' %(client_id, request_token)
access_token_url = 'https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token'

print('Visit the below link in a web browser to get an access PIN:\n')
print(auth_url)
client_pin = input('Enter PIN: ')

c = Client(
    token_endpoint=access_token_url,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret)

c.request_token(code = client_pin)

data = c.request('/devices')
print(data)
```

---

I get this output (Ignore the errors here - this is just proof that Client gets created and used and a valid token is obtained. This is currently the only way to get the access_token to print):

---

```
Visit the below link in a web browser to get an access PIN:

https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=VALID_ID&state=state
Enter PIN: [ENTERED_A_VALID_PIN]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\nest_testing_sanction.py", line 29, in <module>
    data = c.request('/devices')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction\__init__.py", line 169, in request
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction\__init__.py", line 211, in transport_query
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 284, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 313, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'None/devices?access_token=[VALID_TOKEN]'
```

---

I get no 'Client initiated' printed when creating a Client class. Nothing I do to `__init__.py` takes effect. Is it cached somewhere with the stock version?

---

`__init__.py` source: http://pastebin.com/TksTyZT4

---

Modified function (As seen in the `__init__.py` that is referred to by the error output above):

```
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, auth_endpoint=None, token_endpoint=None,
        resource_endpoint=None, client_id=None, client_secret=None,
        token_transport=None):

        assert token_transport is None or hasattr(token_transport, '__call__')

        self.auth_endpoint = auth_endpoint
        self.token_endpoint = token_endpoint
        self.resource_endpoint = resource_endpoint
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.access_token = None
        self.token_transport = token_transport or transport_query
        self.token_expires = -1
        self.refresh_token = None

        print('Client initiated') # Added this line - not getting executed
```

I also modified this function (presumably same or similar issue as above):

```
def request_token(self, parser=None, redirect_uri=None, **kwargs):

    kwargs = kwargs and kwargs or {}

    parser = parser or _default_parser
    kwargs.update({
        'client_id': self.client_id,
        'client_secret': self.client_secret,
        'grant_type': 'grant_type' in kwargs and kwargs['grant_type'] or \
            'authorization_code'
    })
    if redirect_uri is not None:
        kwargs.update({'redirect_uri': redirect_uri})

    msg = urlopen(self.token_endpoint, urlencode(kwargs).encode(
        'utf-8'))
    data = parser(msg.read().decode(msg.info().get_content_charset() or
        'utf-8'))

    for key in data:
        setattr(self, key, data[key])

    if hasattr(self, 'expires_in'):
        try:
            # python3 dosn't support long
            seconds = long(self.expires_in)
        except:
            seconds = int(self.expires_in)
        self.token_expires = mktime((datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(
            seconds=seconds)).timetuple())

    #
    # I added all these prints and the return - no dice
    #
    print('***************************************************')
    print('Access Token: %s' %self.access_token)
    print('Token Life: %s' %self.token_expires)
    print('***************************************************')

    return self.access_token
```

1. How is it possible that the lines I added are getting ignored?
2. What do I have to do to get them to be executed?

The only thing I can think of is that there is another version of the file that is getting used but I have no idea where that might be or if that is the case.

Comment: Didn't you ask a question very similar to this earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a stale .pyc file that needs to get deleted.  Depending on how you are running the code, it may be getting compiled to byte-code which is stored in a .pyc file.  However, when you make changes to your source in your .py, it doesn't overwrite the existing .pyc when you re-run.  This happens if your code is in a module that you are importing.  Look for `__init__.pyc` and delete that bad boy.

Edit, after chat we discovered:

`__init__.py` being imported was located at C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\**sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction**\__init__.py while the `__init__.py` being edited was located at C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\**sanction**\__init__.py.

`sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg` wasn't actually a folder but a file and held priority on the import for some reason (unknown, but likely due to a bad install).

Comment: I've got quite a few of those. Is it safe to delete them all or do I need to be careful? `__init__.cpython-34.pyc` to be exact.

Comment: It's safe to delete them, you can always re-create them from your .py files.  Think of them as a cache of your code, they enable the interpreter to load code faster and are totally safe to nuke en masse .  Just be careful to only delete files ending in .pyc and not .py .  On *nix: `find . | grep -E '\.pyc$' | xargs rm`

Comment: Hmm, no luck unfortunately. I even deleted all *.pyc in the Python34 directory.

Comment: What about site-packages?  It should be in the same directory as `__init__.py`

Comment: Yeah that too. It was recursive. So maybe this is part of the problem but there is/was no .pyc in the `__init__.py` directory `(C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sanction)`.

Comment: Recommend putting prints as the first statement in each function to make sure they're actually getting called

Comment: Both were ignored. I put one in the `__init__()` and one in `.request_token()` right at the top and deleted all *.pyc again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63432/discussion-between-erlvolton-and-enigma).

Comment: After chat we figured out that `python setup.py install` made an egg folder that was somehow messing this up, I have no idea how but after deleting that folder things worked as expected.  I think Enigma is going to switch to using pip in the future.  Does anyone know why the egg that setup.py installed was causing stale code to run?